# Responsive Menu toggle goes invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to toggle a responsive menu, upon the toggle and event function. The menu slides invisibly at the bottom of the page.

```
<div class="header">
    <span class="navButton"></span>  
    <ul class="nav">  
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  
        <li><a href="journey.html">The Journey</a></li>  
        <li><a href="getintouch.html">Get In Touch</a></li>  
    </ul>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {  
         position: relative;  
         text-align: center;  
         width: 100%;  
         background-color: black;  
     }  
     .nav>li {  
         display: none;          
     }        
     .navButton{  
         display: block;  
         background-color: black;  
         color: white;  
         font-size: 40px;  
         text-align: center;  
         cursor: pointer;  
     }  
     .navButton:before {  
         content: "Menu";  
     }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
     $(".navButton").click(function () {          
         $(".nav").slideToggle();          
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code you are hiding all your `li`s, so when you toggle the `display` of the `ul`, the `li`s are still hidden. Remove the `display:none;` on the `li` and add it to the `ul` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {      
     $(".navButton").click(function () {          
         $(".nav").slideToggle();          
     });
});
```

```css
.nav {  
   position: relative;  
   text-align: center;  
   width: 100%;  
   background-color: black;
   display:none;
}
.navButton{  
   display: block;  
   background-color: black;  
   color: white;  
   font-size: 40px;  
   text-align: center;  
   cursor: pointer;  
}  
.navButton:before {  
   content: "Menu";  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
    <span class="navButton"></span>  
    <ul class="nav">  
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  
        <li><a href="journey.html">The Journey</a></li>  
        <li><a href="getintouch.html">Get In Touch</a></li>  
    </ul>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have linked the script tag.
Just change this

```
.nav {  
     position: relative;  
     text-align: center;  
     width: 100%;  
     background-color: black;  
 }  
 .nav>li {  
     display: none;          
 }
```

with

```
.nav { 
 position: relative;
 display:none;
 background-color: #000;
 text-align: center; 
 width:100%; 

}
```